# search functionality does not works

Tags: ionic3, filtering, angular5

I have created online shopping application in which I have  create search functionality in my project.I am listing all the order placed by the customer to the particular shop.now i want to give search functioality to shop keeper over the order details. but I got issue says

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Below is my code:
.html:

```html
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="terms" (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

.ts:

```ts
loadedCountryList: Array<any>;
  countryList: Array<any>;
  countryRef: firebase.database.Reference;

    ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.countryRef = firebase.database().ref('/order_details');
        this.countryRef.on('value', countryList => {
          let countries = [];
          countryList.forEach( country => {
            countries.push(country.val());
            return false;
          });

          this.countryList = countries;
          this.loadedCountryList = countries;
        });
      }
     initializeItems(): void {
        this.countryList = this.loadedCountryList;
      }
        getItems(searchbar) {
          // Reset items back to all of the items

          this.initializeItems();

          // set q to the value of the searchbar
          var q = searchbar.srcElement.value;

          console.log('q =' + q);
          // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
          if (!q) {
            return;
          }

          this.countryList = this.countryList.filter((v) => {

            if (v.name && q) {
              if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
          });

          console.log(q, this.countryList.length);

        }
```

Comment: where is `countryList` initialized? Seems like its undefined when filter code is executed

Comment: its been intialized before the contrustructor.

Comment: maybe it's not yet set when you type in search? what does `console.log(q, this.countryList.length);` log? You can try having a check before filtering

Comment: i m having issue while  `this.countryList = this.countryList.filter((v) => {`

Comment: try `this.countryList = this.countryList? this.countryList.filter((v) => {...}):[]` . Also did you console log the list in intialization?

Comment: 'console.log(q, this.countryList.length);' shows the input i m giving and length of countryList. like 'soa 5'. But my search is not being take place

Comment: try the check...

Comment: "try the check..." check what?

Comment: put a check for undefined state of `countryList`.

Comment: countryList is not undefined. I can get the length of it and also value.i just wanted to filter the data from data of contrylist

Comment: you are retreiving from firebase which is async and could be the reason why you are getting undefined (searching before data load). your filter function itself looks fine. also I would use `this.terms` instead of q

Comment: i had also change this.terms with Q. but still search is not functioninig

Comment: I think `countryList` should be `countryList: Array<any> = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you're retrieving all items after the page has loaded. This could work but then the bug might occur that when you type, the data hasn't finished loading yet. Now you're saying this is not the issue but it might become one later on so let's fix it as well.

So let's rewrite your code a little bit.

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="allCountries" [(ngModel)]="terms" (ionInput)="getItems()"></ion-searchbar>
<!-- show a loading paragraph when countries are being fetched -->
<p *ngIf="!allCountries">Loading....</p>
```

And your ts: (renamed `loadedCountryList` to `allCountries` cuz I liked it better)

```
allCountries: Array<any>;
countryList: Array<any>;
countryRef: firebase.database.Reference;

ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.countryRef = firebase.database().ref('/order_details');
    this.countryRef.on('value', countryList => {
      let countries = [];
      countryList.forEach( country => {
        countries.push(country.val());
        return false;
      });

      this.countryList = countries;
      this.allCountries = countries;
    });
  }

 getItems() {
    // also check for no input
    if (!this.terms || this.terms == '') {
      // if no term is entered you might want to reset the search
      this.countryList = this.allCountries;
      return;
    }
    // allCountries isn't edited by the filter function so you can use that one
    this.countryList = this.allCountries.filter((v) => {
      if (v.name) {
        if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.terms.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

And then display your `countryList` somewhere :)

Comment: Great JOb @Ivaro18. Thank you so much for this lovely descriptive ans you just made my day!